# pytorch : Runtime error using Distributed with gloo

Tags: distributed, pytorch

I am trying to use the PyTorch distributed package and gloo backend.

But, I get the following error.

Master:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Distributed.py", line 169, in <module>
    init_processes(args.rank, size, run)
  File "Distributed.py", line 80, in init_processes
    dist.init_process_group(backend=backend, rank=rank, world_size=size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/distributed/__init__.py", line 49, in init_process_group
    group_name, rank)
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at /pytorch/torch/lib/gloo/gloo/transport/tcp/device.cc:127] rp != nullptr. Unable to find address for: <My specified Ip> at /pytorch/torch/lib/THD/process_group/General.cpp:17
```

And otrher worker get:

```py
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at /pytorch/torch/lib/gloo/gloo/transport/tcp/device.cc:127] rp != nullptr. Unable to find address for: 10.37.0.1 at /pytorch/torch/lib/THD/process_group/General.cpp:17
```

Below is how I initialize:

```py
def init_processes(rank, size, fn, backend='gloo'):
    """ Initialize the distributed environment. """

    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = <My specified Ip>
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '8888' if rank == 0 else '31566'

    print("Init Processes ->", 'backend:', backend, 'rank:', rank, 'MASTER_ADDR:', os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'],
          'MASTER_PORT:', os.environ['MASTER_PORT'])
    dist.init_process_group(backend=backend, rank=rank, world_size=size)
    fn(rank, size)
```

Any thoughts on what may be causing this or how I can fix it ? Thx

ps. I use docker env with python 3.5 and PyTorch 0.3.1 with cuda9.0.

Comment: Hi, is MASTER_ADDR the ip of the rank 0? From documentation: MASTER_ADDR - required (except for rank 0); address of rank 0 node

Comment: Yes, MASTER_ADDR  is the ip of the rank 0. If I change backend from 'gloo' to 'tcp', the code is work.

Answer (score 0):

Gloo cannot bind those IPs. The solution is to give docker access to the machine network interfaces.

The simplest way is to add `--network host` to the `docker run` command.

In this way docker has access to all the interfaces (and IPs) of the host machine. So you can use for `MASTER_ADDR` the IP of the host machine of the rank0 node.

By default docker creates a "bridge network". This means that the container has a private IP (as an example 172.17.X.X) and cannot directly access the host interfaces.